# How to reconize in the right version?

Tags: visual-studio, versioning

We are working with visualstudio and svn. In svn we have 2 versions we work with: A current version where we only do bugfixes and a development version where we build in new functionality. Now it sometimes happen that updates need to be done manually in both versions. In that case i open both versions. The main problem with this is that it's really hard to see in which version you are working. My question is: What is the best way to solve this? Is there a way to have the version you are working with on the screen all the time, or to assign an icon to a specific version?

So in short: whats the easiest way to see the current version of the project you are working with?

Comment: Alternative solution (unrelated to your concrete question): Do bugfixes only once (in the development version) and svn-merge them into the other version.

Comment: Yes this is what usually happens. But in some cases the bug fix in the develpment version is diffirent from the current version. Because there are made some architectural changes.